# Using Burst Compile attribute on methods

Tags: unity, optimization

Can we use `BurstCompile` attribute without using any Jobs or ECS System in Unity? does adding `[BurstCompile]` attribute before methods bring us any benefits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The burst compiled version of a method is called only by the job system. Regular C# scripting tasks you do in Unity without jobs will not benefit from the burst compile attribute.